# File not being released

Tags: python, winapi, ms-access

Ok so I have to run some queries in access 07 then compact and repair it. I am using python and win32com to do this. The code I'm currently using is this.

```
import os;
import win32com.client;
DB1 = 'db1.mdb'
DB2 = 'db1N.mdb'
DB3 = 'db2.mdb'
DBR = r'db1.mdb'
access = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
access.OpenCurrentDatabase(DBR)
DB = access.CurrentDb()
access.DoCmd.OpenQuery("1")
access.DoCmd.OpenQuery("2")
access.DoCmd.OpenQuery("3")
access.CloseCurrentDatabase()
access.Application.Quit();
os.system('copy "db1.mdb" "db2.mdb"')
access = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
access.CompactRepair(DB3,DB2)
access.Application.Quit();
os.remove("db2.mdb")
os.remove("db1.mdb")
os.rename("db1N.mdb","db1.mdb")
```

The problem is that I get this error.

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'db1.mdb'
```

I dont know why I am getting this error seeing as I am quiting access which should close the file. Any Idea how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with COM, but if the `Quit()` returns quickly, it could be trying to reopen the database before the previous instance of Access has finished closing down. As a quick and dirty hack, you could use `time.sleep` to stick a small delay in there.

Comment: I have tried that as well with no luck.

Comment: oops I was cleaning the code up a little to make it easier to read DB1 is suppose to equal 'db1.mdb'

Comment: The second to last line.  os.remove("db1.mdb")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code includes this line:

```
DB = access.CurrentDb()
```

When that line executes, `CurrentDb()` references *db1.mdb*.  Then you later get *WindowsError* at:

```
os.remove("db1.mdb")
```

So I'm wondering if the variable DB still holds a reference to *db1.mdb*.  Perhaps you could first try `del DB` before `os.remove()`.

Or, since your code isn't actually using that DB variable, just get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to get your example to work for me.  To solve your problem add DB.Close();

```
import os;
import win32com.client;
path='C:/project/714239'
os.chdir(path)
DB1 = 'db1.mdb'
DB2 = 'db1N.mdb'
DB3 = 'db2.mdb'
access = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
access.OpenCurrentDatabase(path + '/' + DB1, False)
DB = access.CurrentDb()

DB.Close(); #ADDED THIS

access.CloseCurrentDatabase()
access.Application.Quit();

os.system('copy ' + DB1 + ' ' + DB2)

access = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
access.CompactRepair(path + '/' + DB2, path + '/' + DB3, True)
access.Application.Quit();

os.remove(DB2)
os.remove(DB1)
os.rename(DB3,DB1)
```

Comment: You could drop those semicolons while you are at it.